# Bash command after sshpass not executed

Tags: bash, ssh, process, bash-scripting

Why are commands after sshpass not executed?
Should I somehow signal that the ssh connection has been terminated?

```
#!/bin/bash


SCRIPT="cd /proj  
    ./run_server &                       
    sleep 2                                     
    ./run_process2 &                      
    sleep 3"                                     





if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
        echo "Wrong number of arguments. usage: " $0 " name(or IP address)"
else
        sshpass -p "aaaa" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@"$1" "${SCRIPT}" 
        echo "123"          #< --------- This command is not executed
        python ./commands.py
fi
```

Comment: I suspect the ssh command is still running - waiting for the background processes to finish. Might be worth checking in another terminal what processes are running.

Comment: @DouglasLeeder thanks for help, Can I tell ssh not to wait for them?

Answer (score 1):

```
SCRIPT="cd /proj  
    ./run_server &                       
    sleep 2                                     
    ./run_process2 &                      
    sleep 3"                                     
...
sshpass -p "aaaa" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@"$1" "${SCRIPT}"
```

The ssh session will only close when the remote SSH server sees an end-of-file condition on the standard output of the commands run in the script. If you want `run_server` and `run_process2` to continue running after the ssh session ends, you have to make sure those processes aren't holding open the script's standard output. You could do that by redirecting their standard output somewhere else:

```
SCRIPT="cd /proj  
    ./run_server > /dev/null 2>/dev/null < /dev/null &                       
    sleep 2                                     
    ./run_process2 > /dev/null 2>/dev/null < /dev/null &                      
    sleep 3"
```

This redirects all of the standard file descriptors just to be safe. I believe that ssh is mainly concerned with standard output.

Comment: I will try this out tomorrow, thanks for your help!